# Can I wire-nut together and cut a switch out of my overhead fan?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, switch

I have replaced my bathroom extractor fan with a new model. The new model comes with a single-gang controlled switch which is wireless. You can slot it into the 1-gang box, but it doesn't need any wiring in. It takes a AAA battery.

Currently I still have the old switch in box, and the wireless just sits on the counter.

Does it violate any electrical code (I'm in CT, USA) if I just wire-nut and tape up the wires in the box, and remove the old switch? What's the best way to permanently join those wires. I'd actually like to do it all correctly.

The specific model is: https://www.homedepot.com/p/NuTone-ChromaComfort-110-CFM-Ceiling-Bathroom-Exhaust-Fan-w-Customizable-Multi-Color-LEDs-and-Smart-Phone-App-AERN110RGBL/307771471

Wall control is section 11: https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/85/85b96547-666a-4f8e-a586-4c4ecfc0b214.pdf

The wall control unit feels too big, if there's an existing switch behind the front panel.

Comment: In my jurisdiction a switch is still required, some MFG’s have a holster that attaches to or replaces the plate but the switch toggle is still there when the remote is pulled out of the pocket or holster.

Comment: Thanks - I added some relevant model links. The switch panel has batteries behind it, so I don't think the box is deep enough to fit over the cover. Then seems odd to have two sets of switches in the boxes. Would also need to go from a 3-gang to a 4-gang, as there's another box for vanity light switches, and one for GFCI outlets. Didn't want to add that 4th box.

Comment: The model I am talking about in some cases just double sticks to the existing switch plate, a nicer brand replaces the cover plate. Use caution there are a lot of “not code compliant” things out there. Is the device UL listed?

Comment: Yes - it's UL listed: 1-UL Listed,Energy Star,HVI Certified,cUL Listed,cULus Listed

Comment: Your intention is to hard-wire the fan into the circuit, so that it's always energized, and then the only way to turn it off will be a handheld wireless controller? This sounds kind of sus to me. Wireless controllers tend to break, get jammed by other frequencies, and do all kinds of other weird crazy stuff. And it is surprisingly easy to lose track of them, drop them, et cetera.

It seems bad for there to be a potential situation where the wireless controller is messed up and it becomes impossible to turn off the fan.

Comment: @TungstenWizard - well, that's why I'm asking. In this case, I want to put the remote control faceplate over the wire-nutted wires, so I can't lose it, and it remains close to the fan, roughly 5 ft. In addition, I could remove the fan cover and just unplug it, if necessary, but I do understand your concern, which is I why I asked.

Answer (score 2):

With all the new technology it seems the NEC and local codes are having a hard time keeping up. This may be one example.
I'm probably over my head here but it seems logical that securely wire-nutting them would certainly be safe. They are in an accessible, approved box. There is still a  switch control which has UL approval although it's technically in the fan/light assembly. I'm not suggesting you do this without checking your local and NEC codes. If they haven't dealt with this yet I would think it will be happening soon.